# Joining session by steam subsystem in unreal engine 5.1 dosent load the game level

Tags: multiplayer, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

i was trying to do a game on unreal engine 5.1 and making it work with the steam subsystem

the issue i face is when i'm trying to join a session (with another computer connected to the internet, with different steam account and same download region), the session is found, but upon joining, i just return to the lobby level instead of loading into the host's level.

the game is package as shipping
my defaultengine.ini is configured
the steam overlay is showing (steam_appid.txt correctly placed in the Win64 directory of the build)
i'm using the steam advanced session plugin
the host open the level using "?listen" option

i also checked the "Use seamless travel" on the loaded level's gamemode but its not helping

does anyone know why ?
the only related question i found was at [this link](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/join-session-not-loading-level/475411/3)
but it didnt fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to this: https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/ue-5-1-steam-sockets-problem/696726/46

It's a known bug that prevents connecting if you are using steam subsystem. The fix is supposed to be coming in the 5.3, so if you want to fix it yourself, it seems that building unreal from source and setting both `VerifyNetSessionID` and `VerifyNetClientID` to `0` in `StatelessConnectHandlerComponent.cpp` solves the problem and let you connect.

There's another solution that works for some people and doesn't need to build from source, you can try:
Add this to defaultengine.ini and it should work

```
[ConsoleVariables]
net.CurrentHandshakeVersion=2
net.MinHandshakeVersion=2
```